# CodeIgniter dynamic Base URL

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a codigniter project where url structure will be like https://localhost/project_name/abcde/mycontroller/myfunction

Where base_url is `https://localhost/project_name/abcde/`

And`abcde` will come from database.

Means, I want

```
$this->uri->segment(1); //abcde(Comes from database)
$this->uri->segment(2); //controller
$this->uri->segment(3); //function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a pattern for the abcde. It should be something with a common prefix. You can use that common prefix as an identifier in your routes.php and based on that route, direct the user to the controller-method combination. Refer [this guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).